# Reusable method for paging datasets of differing types in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have various data models -- let's called them **Account**, **User**, and **Order**.  (Ultimately there are many more.)

I have views that will display a list of Account objects, User objects, or Order objects.  Each of the views allows for filtering of these objects based on search criteria (each criteria being unique to the object).

What is the best way to implement paging using just a page's view model so that every action model doesn't have to contain some sort of page parameter?  My goal is to get paging info to/from the page view a property on a page's view model.

***Note: here's how I've started to approach this:***

Generic view model:

```
public ListViewModel<T> {
    public List<T> Models {get;set;}
    public PageRange PageRange {get;set;}
}
```

Each view has a view model that may look something like this:

```
public AccountListViewModel : ListViewModel<Account> { }
```

Each view model contains elements helpful to the view (obviously) including criteria that might be passed back to the controller for filtering. So the list action becomes:

```
public ActionResult List(AccountListViewModel viewModel) {
    var accounts = /* retrieve data based on properties of view model */

    var trimmedAccounts = /* skip and take elements from accounts object based on viewModel.PageRange */
    accounts.Models = trimmedAccounts
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

This works except that the query string must contain "PageRange.PageStart=#" (where # is an integer) for it to bind properly.  I'd like to just have MVC invoke binding of PageRange if it detects "start=" in the query string and wire it up to the view model.